# Series of random numbers on a continuous function

Tags: functions, random, random-walk, algorithmic-randomness

At one point, I read about a function used to generate random numbers that follow a continuous pattern. By this I mean random numbers that as a series is random, but in which items tend to be relatively close to their successors and predecessors. In other words, rather than generating a series like the following:

50, 1, 84, 23, 26, 56, 42, 92, 34, 11, 47

This function would generate random numbers like the following:

42, 45, 49, 48, 34, 31, 36, 42, 45, 53, 61

I can't seem to find this function anywhere, and without its name it isn't yielding to search engines. What is it?

#### Update - I Found the Function!

I was watching a series of videos on constructing graphics using almost random noise, when I realized that what the hosts were talking about was exactly what I was looking for back in April 2015: **Perlin noise**

Perlin noise is essentially a continuous "random" function (along any number of dimensions) in which the values at certain points correspond to the values at neighboring points, yielding a smooth, continuous selection of "random" values, associated by proximity. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Seems like a sort of [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). Let me know if you'd like  me to elaborate.

Comment: @QuinnCulver Please, I'm not too familiar with how they can be used to pull random numbers.

Comment: Suppose the $n$-th element of the sequence is $a_n$. Now choose a natural number $k_n$ according to a Poisson distribution, and then flip a coin to determine if $k_n$ will be added or subtracted to $a_n$ to yield $a_{n+1}$. The exponential in the pmf of the Poisson distribution dictates that $k_n$ will usually be close to $0$, so that $a_n$ will be close to $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: Hey @QuinnCulver, I thought you might be interested to know that I found the function I was looking for: Perlin noise

Answer (score 0):

**Using Uniform Random Numbers to Simulate Various Distributions**

Usually, by 'random number' or 'pseudorandom number', we mean an observation $U$ from a uniform distribution on the interval (0, 1). Other distributions are simulated by transforming $U$ to match some other distribution. A histogram of many observations $U$ would have several bars with bases in (0, 1) and
heights nearly equal. Altogether, the histogram has a roughly rectangular
shape, and sometimes uniform distributions are called 'rectangular'.

The simplest case might be to use $60U$ to simulate events randomly
spread over an hour's time. This is another rectangular distribution
but the base of the rectangle is the interval (0, 60).

If you wanted observations confined to the interval (60, 70), you
could use the transformation $10U + 60$. Another rectangular 
distribution with base (60, 70).

Other transformations use nonlinear transformation. For example, 
many observations made with the square root transformation $\sqrt{U}$
would give a histogram that is roughly a right triangle with base (0,1) 
and the tallest end of the hypotenuse on the right side. Admittedly, it is not
immediately obvious why taking the square root gives a triangular-shaped
histogram, but there is a mathematical proof for that.

Your specification that you just want values crowded rather closely
together mainly clustering around 45 is pretty vague. Most statistical
software has pre-programmed transformations (some of them quite
elaborate) to turn uniform $U$'s into various distributional shapes.
So it is not necessary for the user to figure out the transformation needed to get a
desired shape. If you can be more specific what you want, I might be
able to tell you how to simulate the kind of data you want.

Below is an example of 50 observations from a normal population with
population mean 45, population standard deviation 8, and rounded to
integer values. This illustration was done with R statistical software, but
many kinds of software would do the same job about as simply.

Please understand that this is a random procedure, so the next
time I type 'round(rnorm(50, 45, 8))' into R, I will get entirely
different numbers, but still integers in the 'general vicinity' of 45.
Also, 50 observations is not nearly enough to yield a smooth histogram that closely matches the classical bell-shaped curve; 1000 would be better for that. (Numbers in brackets simply give the count out of 50 of the first
number in each row.)

```
 > round(rnorm(50, 45, 8))
  [1] 46 50 51 51 50 51 29 50 48 55 35 41 31 43
 [15] 49 53 53 48 37 48 33 43 40 37 46 43 46 60
 [29] 35 64 57 48 53 48 39 61 44 43 41 33 46 39
 [43] 40 58 45 45 57 29 41 44
```

Comment: I appreciate the meticulous description of what makes numbers random, but the question was really asking about a specific function used to get nearly random numbers that follow a continuous path. I remember reading about how this function is used in a lot of appliance software, but I forget the function name. The general use is to pick a random input as the seed (x) and then pull the series of random numbers at set intervals from the function. For example, { f(5), f(5.05), f(5.10), f(5.15), f(5.2), f(5.25) }

Comment: Maybe you're talking about transforming by the inverse CDF. That method is sometimes used, as are lots of others. If you have a particular task at hand, maybe it is best to focus on describing that, and finding a way to generate the specific kind of data you need.  It will not necessarily be the case that this function you heard about is even applicable here.

Comment: Say you have a robot with two wheels, left and right. You want it to drive randomly, but you don't want to just use random series for the wheel speeds, because it would just spin back and forth, largely in place, not following any direction for more than a fraction of a second. So you plug in numbers from this function as the wheel speeds, and now while the robot drives around randomly, it appears to follow some logical path. That's the example from the article I read.

Comment: Maybe you want some sort of Markov process, where each random number depends on the previous one, but not on the entire past history. Maybe left and right wheels would obey separate processes so there would be random turns. You might look up 'random walks.' Do the wheel speeds change in steps, say by integer values? How often are speeds changed? Soon we're going to get busted for carrying on a back and forth conversation. Maybe close this question out and start another another one specifically about robot wheel speeds and see what ideas emerge.

Comment: Hey Bruce, just wanted to update you. I found the function I was looking for. Any thoughts?